# SyntaxError: invalid syntax vscode

Tags: python, vscode

Quisiera saber por qué me da este error en mi código.
La idea es que se pueda determinar el destino y de acuerdo a este el precio. Si se es mayor o menor a cierta edad un descuento y de acuerdo al peso de la maleta y una multa si se pasa de cierto peso.

Gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ese sería el código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
def main():
     
    VALOR_MULTA = 25000
    
    print("Bienvenidos a la taquilla de su aerolinea: ")
    destino = input("Digite su destino: ")
    edadPasajero = eval(input("Digite edad del pasajero: "))
    pesoMaleta = eval(input("Digite el peso de su maleta: "))
    

    if (destino.lower() == "bogota") or (destino.lower() == "bogotá"):
         valorBaseViaje = 280000
    elif (destino.lower() == "medellín") or (destino.lower() == "medellin"):
          valorBaseViaje = 220000
    elif (destino.lower() == "san andres") or (destino.lower() == "san andrés"):
         valorBaseViaje = 600000
    else:
          valorBaseViaje = 30000

    if edadPasajero < 18:
          valorEdad = valorBaseViaje * 0.35
    elif edadPasajero > 65:
          valorEdad = valorBaseViaje * 0.25
    
    if pesoMaleta > 23:
         kiloExtra = pesoMaleta-23
         precioTotal = valorBaseViaje + valorEdad + (kiloExtra * VALOR_MULTA)
    else:
         precioTotal = valorBaseViaje

    print(f"El valor del viaje es: {precioTotal}")    
main()
```

Comment: Buenas Juan! ¿Podrías adjuntar el error para ver donde se queja concretamente y acotar? gracias!

Comment: podrías agregar el código en texto, por favor.

Comment: Bienvenido Juan Sebastin Belalcazar Ramir a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: no hay necesidad de usar `eval`

Comment: ¿El "eval" no es utilizado cuando se necesiten valores numéricos?

Comment: Puedes hacer un casting al tipo de dato que necesites directamente

Comment: nop, eval se utiliza para ejecutar una sentencia de código de python, si haces `eval("a=10")` entonces se crea una variable llamada `a` con el valor `10`. Utiliza `int()`. Por otra parte, en que estas ejecutando el código? (tipo de shell)

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error crítico, cuando edadPasajero está entre 18 y 25, no entra a ninguna condición del `if`, por lo que aparecerá el mensaje:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'valorEdad' referenced before assignment
```

Si se cumple alguna condición para algún descuento, en la fórmula final de `precioTotal` estás sumando el descuento en vez de restarlo, por lo que a esos usuarios les saldrá más caro el pasaje.

Otra cosa es que si el peso de la maleta es > 23, pero el pasajero tiene menos de 18, o más de 65, no se le aplica multa por sobrepeso.

Como dijeron en los comentarios, no uses `eval()` para capturar enteros. Usa `int()`. Se podría crear una función para evitar errores de entrada, pero por el momento para el ejercicio, con int() está bien.

Una propuesta para corregir los errores en la parte de los cálculos:

```
# ...
    descuento_edad = 0
    if edadPasajero < 18:
        descuento_edad = valorBaseViaje * 0.35
    elif edadPasajero > 65:
        descuento_edad = valorBaseViaje * 0.25

    multaKiloExtra = 0
    if pesoMaleta > 23:
        multaKiloExtra = (pesoMaleta-23) * VALOR_MULTA

    precioTotal = valorBaseViaje - descuento_edad + multaKiloExtra

    print(f"El valor del viaje es: {precioTotal}") 
# ...
```

Una advertencia final es tener cuidado con la indentación. Tienes indentación inconsistente. El estándar más aceptado es 4 espacios por nivel, si lo usas, entonces siempre debe ser así.